# RFID(CR003t) Not working with uno

Tags: arduino, rfid

I got this rfid reader today and it dosnt seem to work.. as i understand, if i connect it's tx to arduinos rx, it should give me an STX value of 02h. Or something like that..
So.. How is this supposed to work exactly..
My code is

```
int incomingByte = 0;   

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);   
}

void loop() {

    incomingByte = Serial.read();


Serial.println(incomingByte,BYTE);
  }
```

As i understand.. i should get a value.

The rx light is also not blinking..

Help!
Have connected everything besides the pin 2 and pin 3..
As required in the datasheet.. have connected an led which is glowing very slightly. And an Antenna.. I do have RFID tags which are supposedly 125 khz but cnt confirm. BUT, It is supposed to return an value to the rx?
Right?
I get an output of ÿÿÿÿÿÿ

Data sheet : [Datasheet](http://www.chinareader.cn/images/_200892414581722949.pdf)

Comment: Cross-posted to/from the [Sparkfun forums](http://forum.sparkfun.com/viewtopic.php?f=32&t=29160)

Answer (score 1):

I can see two possible issues:

1. The `ÿÿÿÿÿÿ` is often an indication of a wrong bitrate setting (but might also be caused by the other possible issue).
2. and I don't know what arguments `println` gets, but normally you would expect text there, and `02h` is a non-printable character.

Answer (score 1):

Is this the same one as from Seeed Studios? It looks like it. In that case, 9600 baud as you're selecting is the right speed.

However you shouldn't use the same serial as the one for the PC, that could be the issue. Rather, use SoftwareSerial (http://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/SoftwareSerial) which will be fine since it works for up to 9600 anyway.

Your code could look something like this:

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
#define rxPin 2
#define txPin 3

SoftwareSerial mySerial= SoftwareSerial(rxPin, txPin);

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  mySerial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(rxPin, INPUT);
  pinMode(txPin, OUTPUT);
}

void loop()
{
  for (int i=0;i<=13;i++)
  {
    Serial.print(mySerial.read(),BYTE);
  }
  Serial.println("   <<Card ID");
  delay(1000);
}
```

which is based on code from this thread in the Arduino forums http://www.arduino.cc/cgi-bin/yabb2/YaBB.pl?num=1248988301/all

Later when/if this becomes its own circuit and you no longer need to use the serial console, you can rip out the SoftSerial stuff and just use the regular Serial peripheral. The main problem now is that the Arduino IDE's serial debug console is actually using the board's RX and TX on pins 1 and 2, so you need others.

Comment: Thanks. Ill check it out. This reader dosnt hav an input rx pin. Just a tx

Comment: of course, you can just skip that pin.